# Installing CJSON in lua with make and luarocks fails

Tags: lua, failed-installation, cjson

my aim is to install cjson with luarocks on Windows 10 (64 Bit), what i've done so far:

**Try the installation via make:**

- put this [luajit installation](https://github.com/hiili/WindowsTorch) on the path "C:\torch" and set all the following path variables manually (see issues)

  - Path = "C:\torch\bin;"%PATH%
  - LUA_CPATH="C:\torch\bin\?.dll;;"
  - LUA_DEV="C:\torch;"
  - LUA_PATH="C:\torch\lua\?;C:\torch\lua\?.lua;C:\torch\lua\?\init.lua;;"
- put this version of [lua-cjson-2.1.0](https://github.com/mpx/lua-cjson/) on the following folder: "C:\Users\username\Desktop\lua-cjson-2.1.0"
- install mingw with make version 3.81, cmake 3.13.2 and add "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\" and  "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\" to the Path variable
- uncomment variables for Windows(MingGW) and setting the PREFIX = C:\torch\ in the Makefile of lua-cjson-2.1.0
- go via admin-shell to "C:\Users\username\Desktop\lua-cjson-2.1.0"
- "**make install**" yields the following output:

```
cc -c -O3 -Wall -pedantic -DNDEBUG  -IC:\torch CJSON_CFLAGS =   -DDISABLE_INVALID_NUMBERS/include -fpic -o lua_cjson.o lua_cjson.c

make: cc: Command not found

make: *** [lua_cjson.o] Error 127`
```

**Another try with luarocks doesn´t work too:**

- call ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64"

  - then call "**luarocks make**" as described in the [cjson-manual](https://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html#_luarocks)
  - this yields the following output:

```
cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Folua_cjson.obj -IC:/torch/include lua_cjson.c -DDISABLE_INVALID_NUMBERS lua_cjson.c

        cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fostrbuf.obj -IC:/torch/include strbuf.c -DDISABLE_INVALID_NUMBERS strbuf.c

        strbuf.c(98): warning C4311: "type conversion": pointer truncation from "strbuf_t *" to "long"

        strbuf.c(172): warning C4311: "type conversion": pointer truncation from  "strbuf_t *" to"long"

        cl /nologo /MD /O2 -c -Fofpconv.obj -IC:/torch/include fpconv.c -DDISABLE_INVALID_NUMBERS fpconv.c

        link -dll -def:cjson.def -out:cjson.dll C:/torch/lib/libluajit.lib lua_cjson.obj strbuf.obj fpconv.obj

        Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.10.25019.0

        Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        Bibliothek "cjson.lib" und Objekt "cjson.exp" werden erstellt.

        lua_cjson.obj : error LNK2019: Reference to unresolved external symbol "strncasecmp" in function "json_is_invalid_number".

cjson.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste Externe

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module cjson.dll`
```

Whats wrong with the installation procedure?

Comment: Is it possible that your installation of Windows is missing some dependencies needed for compilation? Like the ones included with Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: Thanks for answering that quick! I'm not very familiar with VS, i just installed it, because I read that i should call the "luarocks make" after initializing calling the vcvarsall.bat to fix some other cl-command issue. How can i include additional libraries? Is it sufficient to include string.h (original problem: strncasecmp)? For interest: is there a working way of installing the package directly with luarocks in my setup?